# Problema al ejecutar sudo dotnet ef

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Buen dia. Actualmente estoy trabajando con la version dotnet 3.0 en sistema operativo ubuntu 18.04 estoy utilizando entity framework para ello agregue la dependencia:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.0-preview3.19554.8" />
```

Cuando utilizo el comando: 
**$ dotnet ef -h** funciona bien pero si utilizo otras funciones de dotnet como migrate necesita autorizacion sudo, cuando utilizo sudo en el comando:
**$ sudo dotnet ef -h** me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.  
 Possible reasons for this include:  
  You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.  
  You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.  
  You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with 
    this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

ya intente instalarlo de forma global:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

Comment: Usualmente esos problemas se resuelven con `sudo -i` que te genera sesión de superusuario en terminal. O, reinstalando en una sesión de superusuario para que el entorno tenga suficientes privilegios

Comment: ya lo intente y no me funciono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estaba teniendo el mismo inconveniente y pude solucionarlo siguiendo este post
https://superuser.com/questions/1516674/sudo-doesnt-have-access-to-globally-installed-software/1516685#1516685?newreg=25a18232f76c46a3be7effb034abae7e
Básicamente tenés que ejecutar de esta forma dado que cuando haces sudo intenta buscar la configuración en el usuario root
sudo env "PATH=$PATH:/home//.dotnet/tools" dotnet ef 
Saludos.

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/192055)

Comment: you are right, i was not able to make a comment and te rules are not to repeat a question.
I've edited with the solution i've found

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta de que estoy en el post en español : o )
Estaba teniendo el mismo problema y lo pude solucionar siguiendo lo que dice acá
 https://superuser.com/questions/1516674/sudo-doesnt-have-access-to-globally-installed-software/1516685#1516685?newreg=25a18232f76c46a3be7effb034abae7e
Básicamente escribí 
sudo env "PATH=$PATH:/home//.dotnet/tools" dotnet ef migrations add initial
Saludos